# Java FX окна и FXML

Tags: javafx

Есть окно:
public class Main extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("My First App");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

в нем есть кнопка "new window", который переходить к другой окно:

@FXML
    private Button id;

```
@FXML
void initialize() {
    id.setOnAction(event -> {
        FXMLLoader loader =  new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/ex1.fxml"));

        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();

    });
```

в новом окне(ex1.fxml) есть кнопка "Cancel", Kaк оформить кнопку "Cancel" так, чтоб это окно зокрывался,и перещоль переведущую оконо: "sample.fxml".п.с. не нужен создать новый "sample.fxml", а именно возврашатся переведущую оконо. Спосибо!

Comment: [Отметьте ответ верным, получите +2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/291565)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы при закрытии окна возвращалось в нужное, нужно указать это окно в методе `initOwner()`. Например, так:

```
id.setOnAction(event -> {
    ....
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.initOwner(id.getScene().getWindow());
    stage.show();
});
```

Закрыть окно можно, вызвав метод `close()` объекта класса `Stage`. Для кнопки можно назначить такое действие:

```
@FXML
void close(ActionEvent event) {
    Node node = (Node)event.getSource();
    Stage stage = (Stage)node.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
}
```